# How to restore postgresql backup file with different name

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pgadmin

I have taken a backup of a table in pgadmin by rightclick->backup. Now i want to restore that backup with different name so that existing table isn't get affected.

Note - I can rename the existing table and restore the backup file. But often the db server hangs when i rename the active table in production. So this doesn't work for me.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that. You'd have to restore it to a different database...

Comment: Which format did you use?  It offers 4 choices (custom, tar, directory, and plain)